# How to tell if a button click event was triggered by keyboard or mouse in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, button

Is there a simple way to tell what triggered Click event of a Button apart from setting multiple flags in Mouse/Key Up/Down event handlers? I'm currently only interested in distinguishing mouse from everything else, but it would be nice to handle Stylus and other input types if possible. Do I have to create my own button control to achieve this?

Edit: To clarify why I care: in this particular case I'm trying to implement "next" and "previous" buttons for a sort of picture viewer. Pictures in question may be of different size and buttons' positions will change (so they are always centered below picture). It's quite annoying to follow such buttons with mouse if you need to scroll through several pictures, so I want to keep mouse position constant relative to clicked button, but only if it was clicked by mouse, not keyboard.

Edit2: It does not matter whether the buttons are on top or down at the bottom, since the center can change anyway. "Picture viewer" here is just an abstraction and in this particular case it's important for me that top left corner of the picture retains it's position, but it's out of the scope of the question to go in details. Scaling the picture is not so trivial in this sort of application as well, so I do want to know the answer to the question I asked not going into UI implementation discussion.

Comment: Does my answer not give you enough information or am I missing something?

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I did not ask for - handling Mouse/Key Up and Down event handlers separately. Yes, it is a way to do it, but it's not as elegant as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice is KeyboardDevice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead handle specifically the MouseXXX, StylusXXx, and KeyboardXXX events.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on why you would care?

Having written many custom controls myself over the years, I cannot recall one instance where I cared how a click event was triggered. (Except for that pre VB6 control lifecycle glitch that fired the got focus-click-lost focus in a different order depending on whether you clicked a button, used an accelerator key, or pressed ENTER as the default).

Comment: In my case I have a textbox where pushing enter will click a default button. If the user hasn't entered a value I want to warn them (due to previous action this is quite easy to do). However if they click the button itself I assume it was deliberate and they didn't want to enter a value.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it annoying when people place buttons at the bottom of Windows forms and web pages. Read some of the literature on UI and you will find that most people don't even get that far if they don't find something interesting on the page/form. I like to be able to click next as soon as I know the content is of no interest to me, so keep the nav buttons prominent at the top.

I would put the prev/next at the top of the picture where you can control their position. Dancing those buttons around goes against most opinions on UI consistency. Further creating a different experience for a mouse user versus a keyboard user also goes against most current wisdom on good UI design.

The alternative is to choose a constant max size a picture can obtain on the UI and if it exceeds that scale to fit, otherwise allow it to change freely within a frame. This keeps your buttons at the same place if you absolutely must have them on the bottom.

Comment: I beg to disagree - just look at Picasa slide show or Windows Picture Viewer and you'll find those buttons at the bottom. Your personal preferences are quite understandable, but my vision for UI in this case is different. Anyway, this question is not about UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an enumeration with the different devices, have a global property that you set every time the mouse/keyboard/etc. is initiated, and just refer to this when needed.