# WPF MouseEnter event is fired if spacebar is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, button, event-handling, mouseenter

I want to handle a buttons `MouseEnter` event only for mouse actions. So I have to detect if `MouseEnter` is triggered by mouse or by keyboard.

```
private void button_onMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    if (!button.IsMouseOver)            return; // not working
    if (!button.IsMouseDirectlyOver)    return; // not working
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check most recent input device

```
if (InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice is KeyboardDevice);
```

as been discussed here:

[How to tell if a button click event was triggered by keyboard or mouse in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346973/how-to-tell-if-a-button-click-event-was-triggered-by-keyboard-or-mouse-in-wpf)